# Jackson and App Engine causing NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: json, google-app-engine, jackson

There are a few questions about this, but all are for Jackson 1.x. I'm using Jackson 2.4.3 with App Engine SDK 1.9.15 and I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper
```

I've tried using the jackson-all-1.9.11.jar also but still get the same issue.

If I import the repackaged jackson from com.google.appengine.repackaged then everything works fine, but I get the following warning which makes it sound like a bad thing to do.

> WARNING: ..... is not part of App Engine's supported API. You are
>   strongly discouraged from using this class - your app may stop working
>   in production at any moment.

Comment: The Jackson 2.x has package `com.fasterxml.jackson`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this error indicates that the required jar is missing from `/WEB-INF/lib` folder, or that there are several conflicting jars (with the same classpath) in that folder.

You may not get this error in your IDE if you added this jar to the project's classpath. If you use Eclipse, start by selecting your project and looking into the Problems tab. You may see a warning there that a specified resource is not available on the server. Right click on this warning and choose "Copy..." option.

Otherwise, manually add this jar to the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder.